# c# class to Js class?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a class Person in c#.

I want to be able to do in my js :

```
var p = new Person();
```

Later Im sending p object to an ashx via jQuery Ajax

What are the libraries ( jQuery ? xxx ?) which can help me do that ?

I know that Ajaxtookit has a attribute  : ScriptService

But Im not sure HOw good this solution.

Comment: Are you using WebForms or MVC?

Comment: You don't do this. You can't just port a C# class to JavaScript. You redefine the "class" in JavaScript

Comment: @Raynos you are wrong . there are libraries which do that. I saw it  - e.g : scriptService attribute.

Comment: @RoyiNamir auto generating javascript from C# is a great way to generate mediocre code that will leak around the edges. Do it properly.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - What version of .NET are you using? If you're using .NET 4, you could utilize the new `dynamic` keyword using something like [this](http://www.drowningintechnicaldebt.com/ShawnWeisfeld/archive/2010/08/22/using-c-4.0-and-dynamic-to-parse-json.aspx).

Comment: @M.Babcock ver 4. How do i take the object from the request.form and use dynamic with it ? ( can you please post an answer ?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use ASPX PageMethods with jQuery. So start working on the server by defining a model:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

then you could define a page method in some aspx page (`/foo.aspx`):

```
public partial class _Foo : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    [WebMethod]
    public static string SavePerson(Person p)
    {
        // do some processing with the person
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

and finally invoke this page method:

```
var p = {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Smith'
};
$.ajax({
    url: '/foo.aspx/SavePerson',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/javascript; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(p),
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result.d);
    }
});
```

The JSON.stringify method illustrated here is built in modern browsers. If you need to support legacy browsers you could include the [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html) script to your page.

---

UPDATE:

As requested in the comments section here's how you could design a generic ASHX handler that will receive this request, do some processing and return a JSON response:

```
public class Foo : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
        {
            Person person = (Person)serializer.Deserialize<Person>(reader.ReadToEnd());
            // do some processing with the person

        }
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

        var result = serializer.Serialize(new { data = "Hello World" });
        context.Response.Write(result);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and the request:

```
var p = {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Smith'
};
$.ajax({
    url: '/foo.ashx',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(p),
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result.data);
    }
});
```

Comment: I dont use aspx jus ashx so i dont have webmethod attr. How can i change your code to work with ASHX file ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, answer updated with an example using a generic ASHX handler.

Comment: How come I cant see the values in the Request.form but only in context.Request.InputStream ? ( you sent it as post  so why it aint show you in request.form ?)

Comment: @RoyiNamir, in this example we are sending a JSON request into the stream directly. There is no Request.Form. You cannot use this if you want to send a JSON request. If you don't want to send a JSON request, remove the `JSON.stringify` call. Then you can use `Request["FirstName"]` inside the handler to fetch individual properties. But why would you need this if you already have the entire object?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6509/discussion-between-royi-namir-and-darin-dimitrov)

Answer (score 2):

use [json](http://www.json.org/), convert your c# object to json using [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) Library

Comment: That just converts the data to the JSON format, that doesn't allow for using C# written classes in javascript in any way. It doesn't allow sending, but that's only part.

Answer (score 2):

The correct thing to do is define a person prototype in JavaScript

```
var Person = {
  someMethod: function () {

  },
  someMoreMethods: function () {

  }
};
```

Then you get your C# server to send a serialized version of it's `Person` instance as JSON and on the client you just have an xhr handler

```
xhr.addEventListener("load", function () {
  var personJSON = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  var personInstance = Object.create(Person);
  var person = extend(personInstance, personJSON);
});
```

Here you take the json data for the person which are all the attributes. You create a new prototypical instance of the Person "class" so the instance has all the methods. You then extend the instance with the data / attributes you got over JSON.

note you have to implement `extend`, a naive implementation would be

```
function extend(target, source) {
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(source).forEach(function (name) {
    var pd = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, name);
    Object.defineProperty(target, name, pd);
  });
  return target;
}
```

**Disclaimer:** example code uses ES5, deal with legacy browser engines in a sensible manner yourself.